# Making Responsive Table Using Pixel Instead Of Percentage

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make table responsive according to the window size. I know that by making it responsive, you have to use percentage rather than pixels for the width. Is there anyway to make it responsive by making use of pixels e.g. `width="1000px"` instead of `width="100%"`?

```
<table width="1000px" border="1">
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td>bye</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

-> not responsive

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td>bye</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

-> responsive

Comment: Using `min-width: 500px` then use `width:100%`

Comment: Are you using media queries to change the CSS based on viewport size? If so, then yes, you could use pixels. It somewhat defeats the purpose on some levels, but there's no reason you can't technically use pixels.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to use pixels, but you can workaround it using Media Queries. They allow you to change page stylization at some resolution.

Answer (score 1):

try this. I think this is what you're looking.

```
<style>
#resp{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin:center;
border:1px solid black;
width:900px;
max-width:100%;
}
</style>

<div id ="resp">
 <table width = "100%" border="1">
  <tr>
   <td>hello</td>
   <td>bye</td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pixels give your table a fix width and so it isn't responsive. With javascript you can update the width while resizing your window, but with css percentage styles, it would be much cleaner.

With javascript at the bottom of your html page you can give your table element a responsive width in 'px':

```
//resize function for the table
function resizeTable() {
  //find table by id and style the width with the window width in px
  document.getElementById("responsiveTable").style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
}

//do the resize on page load
resizeTable();
//do the resize on every window resize
window.onresize = resizeTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you have to use media queries in your css. 
As the screen is made wider the table will expand once the viewport exceeds the min width defined in the media query.

For example:

```
table {width:300px}
@media(min-width:768px){
  table{width:500px}
}
@media(min-width:992px){
  table{width:800px}
}
@media(min-width:1200px){
  table{width:1000px}
}
```

So starting from a narrow/mobile width, the table will jump up in width from 300px to 500px and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `window.innerWidth` using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("table").width(window.innerWidth);
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   $("table").width(window.innerWidth);
});
```

Comment: Yes, use can dynamically resizing the table using JS, but this is really slow and the user experience will not be very good.